# Qt Program Unexpectedly Finished

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, autocomplete

I am trying to create a autocompleting line edit in Qt but my program is crashing for reasons I cant understand, the code that makes it crash is

```
model_Customer->setTable("Customer");
model_Customer->select();
model_Product->setTable("Product");
model_Product->select();
Account_completer->setModel(model_Customer);
Product_completer->setModel(model_Product);
Account_completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
Product_completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
AutoComplete();
ui->lineEdit_Invoice_Account->setCompleter(Account_completer);
ui->lineEdit_Invoice_Product->setCompleter(Product_completer);
```

my .h file is below

```
QSqlDatabase db;
QSqlTableModel *model_Customer;
QSqlTableModel *model_Product;
QCompleter *Account_completer;
QCompleter *Product_completer;
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you make new instances of models? Like : `model_Customer = new QSqlTableModel(this,db);`

Comment: Thank you i just noticed that i had forgot to add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to use an unallocated pointer, you are using a dangling pointer the behavior of which is undefined, but most of the time, it is a crash. At worst, it is a bug that makes your program behave weird.

Please remember to always initialize your pointers, even if it is `0`, `NULL` or `nullptr`. The best is if you get used to uniform initialization in-place should you be able to utilize C++11 or later.

Also, these issues are relatively easy to spot by using tools like valgrind, gdb and other memory tracers.